# UsedRange.Count counting wrong

Tags: vba, excel

**Summary:** I'm taking a row of data from one sheet and pasting it into another, however the sheet would be a daily use kind of thing where new data is just entered below old data.

**Problem:** On each new run, 7 is consistently added to the `UsedRange.Count`. For example: on one run the `UsedRange.Count` will be 7; the next time I run through the function the count will be 14.

**What I'm Looking For:** Why is this the case and is there a way to help `UsedRange` be more accurate

-I've included the entire Function for references' sake.

```
Function eftGrabber()

        Dim usedRows As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        ChDir "\\..."       

        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "\\...\eftGrabber.xlsm"

        usedRows = Sheets("EFT").UsedRange.Count

        Windows("Data").Activate

        Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A11").EntireRow.Copy

        Windows("eftGrabber").Activate

        Sheets("EFT").Range("A" & usedRows + 1).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        i = usedRows

        Do                            'THIS LOOP DELETES BLANKS AFTER POSTING NEW LINES

            Range("A" & i).Select

            If Range("A" & i) = "" Then

                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

            End If

              i = i - 1

        Loop Until i = 1

        Windows("eftGrabber").Activate

        ActiveWorkbook.Save

  Windows("eftGrabber").Close

End Function
```

Let me know if I've left out any important details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mike, you should always avoid using usedrange. Instead find the last row and use that for pasting. See this link to find the last row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change: `usedRows = Sheets("EFT").UsedRange.Count`

To: `usedRows = Sheets("EFT").Range("A" & Sheets("EFT").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Where "A" can be changed to whichever row you wish to count the total number of columns.

There is a danger in using `UsedRange` because it factors in such things and formatted cells with no data and other things that can give you unexpected results, like if you are expecting your data to start in Range("A1"), but it really starts in another range!

I will say, however, that If you really wish to use `UsedRange`, your code above is still wrong to get the rows. Use this instead `UsedRange.Rows.Count` or to get the last absolute cell of the UsedRange, use `UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`

Comment: oh man, didn't realize I completely forgot the `.Rows` part. Thats probably why.

Comment: In excel 2016 I get 1048576 value  in UsedRange.Rows.Count and UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row   although I have just 99 lines used! I guess it happens because I probably selected a whole column to set its color, but this is insane... How can I get excel counting cells with values rather than cells with formats?

Answer (score 5):

This two line do the  magic

```
  usedCol = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
  usedRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

For more info visit  Microsoft's site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the discussion...

`.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and `.UsedRange.Columns.Count` work fine provided there is something in cell A1.  Otherwise need to use the SpecialCells solution.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: No need to have something in A1 if you use:  Sheet.UsedRange.Row + Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

Answer (score 1):

“UsedRange” works if you use it like this >>

```
x := Sheet.UsedRange.Row + Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1;
y := Sheet.UsedRange.Column + Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1;
```

Problem with SpecialCells is that you can't use it on a Protected Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have contiguous sheet (i.e. no blank cells), and you sheet starts in A1, then I have found that

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

gives the most reliable results.