# Macro to copy a value into another cell if a criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to write a macro that for example, would copy the value from column A where the condition of cheese was met, and then pasted this value into the adjacent cell in the next column. Where would you start with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without** a macro:

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="CHEESE",A2,"")
```

and copy down

**With** a macro:

```
Sub Cheesey()
    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
        If r.Text = "CHEESE" Then
            r.Offset(0, 1) = "CHEESE"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Use caution with UsedRange http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886284/usedrange-count-counting-wrong