# UsedRange.Calculate doesn't see to reset the scroll bars in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet I know is going to to contain a little bit of data, about 40 rows, which I need to clear out between runs. So I did this:

```
ThisSheet.Range("A2:ZZ999").Clear
ThisSheet.UsedRange.Calculate
```

I was under the impression that the second line would reset UsedRange and thus avoid the last row being a previous value. This appears to work.

However, when I look at the sheet in excel, it scrolls to line 999. The Calculate doesn't seem to fix this.

Did I miss something?

Comment: What is you end goal?

Comment: I seem to remember simply calling `ThisSheet.Usedrange` might have the functionality you're looking for. Can't confirm right now but worth a try.

Comment: Keep in mind that `UsedRange` has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11886420/4717755)

Comment: Re _I was under the impression that the second line would reset UsedRange_ sorry, but no.  First, it only works if you apply it to `ActiveSheet`, secondly you can't use another layer after `UsedRange`.  So it's just `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` (obviously activate the required sheet first).  Then do your calculate separately

Comment: @BigBen - If you have 10 rows of data and then clear down to 999, excel thinks the sheet has 999 rows in UsedRange. This is frustrating because the scroll bars now go WAAAAY past your data.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I don't think either of those points are true. .Calculate does indeed seem to work, and the value returned for ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count is 999 in spite of it not being the active sheet.